# Troubleshoot Android 4.3 webview within an app that requires up-to-date Google Play services

Tags: android-emulator, android-webview, google-chrome-devtools, google-play-services, genymotion

I need to troubleshoot an issue happening in a webview running within my app. This issue only occurs on Android versions lower or equal to 4.3. My app requires an up to date version of Google Play services.

In order to troubleshoot my webview, I usually can run my app under the Android Emulator (with the latest version of Android), then connect to the web view via Chrome (using chrome://inspect) - the web view appears in Chrome and I'm able to browse the DOM and debug.

To run the app under 4.3, I've created (under AVD) a new device from an existing device definition,
then picked the target *Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 18*. I've then installed my app, but when trying to run it, I get the error message "This app won't run unless you update Google Play services.". There's an "Update" button on the previous dialog, but nothing happen when clicking on it.

I then tried to debug my issue using Genymotion. I've created a device under 4.3, followed [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145) to flash my device with the latest Google Play services and installed my app. I can now run the app and reproduce the issue within this simulated environment.

The trick now is to be able to connect to the web view from my local Chrome browser. I've enabled remote debugging as described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#setting-up-device). Now my device appears in Chrome, but the web view is not showing up in the inspector. Similarly, if I open a new tab under the native browser, it won't show up in the remote inspector. If I open a new tab under Android Chrome though, I can see it showing up under my remote Chrome inspector.

I can see two way moving forward and successfully accessing to the DOM of my webview:

- Fixing the "Update" issue under the Android Emulator running 4.3

Or

- Connecting to my web view from my Chrome inspector while running the app under Genymotion

Any idea on how to solve one of these two problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote debugging web views only works on devices with android 4.4 and above.
have a look at this :
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: this was in the doc I linked. Cannot believe that android did not supported that before 4.4, I honestly though by reading it that the web view would need to be configured to be reached by the inspector, vs prior to 4.4 it would always be accessible. Nevermind, gotta find a different way to trouble shoot my issue as chrome inspector seems worthless here.

Answer (score 4):

I have been using [weinre](http://people.apache.org/%7Epmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/) for sometimes. it's a pretty good tool to debug webview for android 4.3 and lower. It provides almost same interface as chrome debugger.

All you need to do are:

**Install weinre**

```
sudo npm -g install weinre
```

**Client side:**

Insert the following code to your webpage `<head>` section.

Note: it's better to put it at end of `<head>` section, otherwise there will be some strange errors and debugger won't show up.

```
<script src="http://<your server ip here>:8081/target/target-script-min.js"></script>
```

**Server side**

```
weinre --boundHost -all- --httpPort 8081
```

**Debugger**

open the debugger tool from weinre from your desktop browser:

```
http://localhost:8081/client/
```

Finally,

select any target in Targets part and then start debugging.

Comment: This works fine on local debug ie on same machine, is there a way to debug a real device connected to the server? Currently I don't see remote devices listed